# Protection for PCB inputs and outputs - ESD, short-circuit, EMI

Tags: esd, emi-filtering

I have a pretty simple board that wires together an Arduino and a screen. It has 3 terminal blocks - power, optical encoder, and stepper outputs (just signals).

Stepper and encoder signals are in the kHz range.

The board draws 80 mA, but I don't have precise control over components potentially soldered into it so I'm using a 300 mA fuse.

I've tried to safeguard the terminals with resistors against both ESD and EMI, but I'm not sure if this is enough. I'm also not sure how to protect the encoder 5 V from ESD.

The goal is to make the board survive bad terminal connections and clear FCC/CE standards. Please advise.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You probably want TVS clamps on the lines. Also "Stepper and encoder signals are in the kHz range" - the clock rate doesn't matter when it comes to EMI; it's the rise/fall time at the switching edge that counts.

Comment: The 1k IO resistors are a prudent choice for the internal ESD diodes.